# Cannot boot in windows anymore after switching from ubuntu to fedora

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot, grub, gparted

I had a dual boot setup in a single drive with ubuntu and windows 10. Ubuntu was installed from the `install alongside windows` option in the installer.
I recently decided to remove ubuntu and install fedora, which I did. But now, Windows no more appear in grub. How can I get Windows back in grub ?

Here is a screenshot of my config from gparted:
[image]

### EDIT

I also tried to run `sudo grub2-mkconfig > /dev/null` to see if windows will be detected, but it is not. Here is the result of the command:

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.11.9-300.fc26.x86_64
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-4.11.9-300.fc26.x86_64.img
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.11.8-300.fc26.x86_64
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-4.11.8-300.fc26.x86_64.img
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.11.8-200.fc25.x86_64
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-4.11.8-200.fc25.x86_64.img
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-0-rescue-99fd01fc6f9e4a34bd2f9ef304078b34
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-0-rescue-99fd01fc6f9e4a34bd2f9ef304078b34.img
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar challenges with combining Windows and Fedora dual-boot.  I use EasyBCD as the boot manager, installed on the Windows side and pretty straightforward.  It's been working fine for 3 years.